# Print values from long array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a long array which looks like this:

```
Kiwwito\TuentiAPI\Object\APIObjectList Object
(
    [objects:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kiwwito\TuentiAPI\Object\User Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 60993525
                            [name] => Danny
                            [surname] => Mathews
                            [avatar] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => http://ak3.img.tuenti.net/HexB8wOXNRSADG6AGQAMgAvAGQ
                                    [1] => 50
                                    [2] => 50
                                )

                            [sex] => 1
                            [phone_number] => 
                            [chat_server] => xmpp4.tuenti.com
                        )

                    [structure:protected] => 
                )
```

The array is much longer than that, but its similar, I want to print the name value for all entries in the array one after another in a list. Hope you understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a bit of both... `$this->objects[0]->data['name']`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php did you mean this, or why cant u use this?

Answer (score 0):

what is a problem with var_dump($var) ? Have you tried it ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in PHP,  but how could that help me? I am a bit lost. var_dump result: http://pastebin.com/1H5NL6vE

Comment: To tell you exact steps, I need to know how your user class is written etc. But you can refer following code to iterate through array:

$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}

Answer (score 0):

or `echo '<pre>',print_r($object, TRUE),'</pre>';`

Comment: Already made that to get what I posted on my question, what i need it to loop printing all the names ( like [name] => Danny in my question ), but just the name value, nothing else